# Application is Blank after adding AppDelegate

Tags: ios, objective-c, onesignal

I have a iOS Application in Cordova with Push Notification implemented using OneSignal.

I have followed all the steps in the documentation given [here](https://documentation.onesignal.com/docs/ios-sdk-setup)

The problem is that, when I install the app using XCode the application asks,

> AppName Would like to send you notification

But after that everything goes black screen.

I assume that it is because of the AppDelegate.m file which is the following

```
/*
 Licensed to the Apache Software Foundation (ASF) under one
 or more contributor license agreements.  See the NOTICE file
 distributed with this work for additional information
 regarding copyright ownership.  The ASF licenses this file
 to you under the Apache License, Version 2.0 (the
 "License"); you may not use this file except in compliance
 with the License.  You may obtain a copy of the License at

 http://www.apache.org/licenses/LICENSE-2.0

 Unless required by applicable law or agreed to in writing,
 software distributed under the License is distributed on an
 "AS IS" BASIS, WITHOUT WARRANTIES OR CONDITIONS OF ANY
 KIND, either express or implied.  See the License for the
 specific language governing permissions and limitations
 under the License.
 */

//
//  AppDelegate.m
//  ReachApp
//
//  Created by ___FULLUSERNAME___ on ___DATE___.
//  Copyright ___ORGANIZATIONNAME___ ___YEAR___. All rights reserved.
//

#import "AppDelegate.h"
#import "MainViewController.h"

#import <OneSignal/OneSignal.h>

@implementation AppDelegate

- (BOOL)application:(UIApplication *)application didFinishLaunchingWithOptions:(NSDictionary *)launchOptions {

    // Replace '11111111-2222-3333-4444-0123456789ab' with your OneSignal App ID.
    [OneSignal initWithLaunchOptions:launchOptions
                               appId:@"11111111-2222-3333-4444-0123456789ab"
            handleNotificationAction:nil
                            settings:@{kOSSettingsKeyAutoPrompt: @false}];
    OneSignal.inFocusDisplayType = OSNotificationDisplayTypeNotification;

    // Recommend moving the below line to prompt for push after informing the user about
    //   how your app will use them.
    [OneSignal promptForPushNotificationsWithUserResponse:^(BOOL accepted) {
        NSLog(@"User accepted notifications: %d", accepted);
    }];

    return YES;
}

@end
```

I have replaced the ID as well. And in XCode logs it display few warning, which are

> 2018-06-29 12:33:16.661 ReachApp[721:311194] DiskCookieStorage
>   changing policy from 2 to 0, cookie file:
>   file:///private/var/mobile/Containers/Data/Application/4C0D3ECB-1F40-4668-BE78-AE1EF3CB7810/Library/Cookies/Cookies.binarycookies
>   2018-06-29 12:33:16.838 ReachApp[721:311194] Called init with app ID:
>   (null) 2018-06-29 12:33:16.934 ReachApp[721:311194] Called init with
>   app ID: Displays_Actual_App_ID_here 2018-06-29 12:33:17.019
>   ReachApp[721:311194] WARNING: OneSignal has detected that your
>   application delegate implements a deprecated method
>   (application:didReceiveLocalNotification:). Please note that this
>   method has been officially deprecated and the OneSignal SDK will no
>   longer call it. You should use UNUserNotificationCenter instead
>   2018-06-29 12:33:17.020 ReachApp[721:311194] WARNING: OneSignal has
>   detected that your application delegate implements a deprecated method
>   (application:handleActionWithIdentifier:forLocalNotification:completionHandler:).
>   Please note that this method has been officially deprecated and the
>   OneSignal SDK will no longer call it. You should use
>   UNUserNotificationCenter instead 2018-06-29 12:33:17.020
>   ReachApp[721:311194] WARNING: OneSignal has detected that your
>   application delegate implements a deprecated method
>   (application:didReceiveLocalNotification:). Please note that this
>   method has been officially deprecated and the OneSignal SDK will no
>   longer call it. You should use UNUserNotificationCenter instead
>   2018-06-29 12:33:17.028 ReachApp[721:311194] WARNING: OneSignal has
>   detected that your application delegate implements a deprecated method
>   (application:handleActionWithIdentifier:forLocalNotification:completionHandler:).
>   Please note that this method has been officially deprecated and the
>   OneSignal SDK will no longer call it. You should use
>   UNUserNotificationCenter instead

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think there are two separate issues. The reason for the blank screen problem probably is that the app doesn't know which View Controller to display. If you are using a storyboard you can set the desired View Controller as 'Initial View Controller'.

Or you can add

`self.window.rootViewController = self.viewController;
[self.window makeKeyAndVisible];`

to the end of:

```
- (BOOL)application:(UIApplication*)application didFinishLaunchingWithOptions:(NSDictionary*)launchOptions
```

just above `return YES;`

Answer (score 0):

Please add below methods to handle notification in your appdelegate.

```
   -(void)application:(UIApplication *)application didRegisterForRemoteNotificationsWithDeviceToken:(NSData *)deviceToken
{
    NSLog(@"Application registered for notification");
}

-(void)application:(UIApplication *)application didFailToRegisterForRemoteNotificationsWithError:(NSError *)error
{
    NSLog(@"Failed to register notification for application");
}

-(void)userNotificationCenter:(UNUserNotificationCenter *)center willPresentNotification:(UNNotification *)notification withCompletionHandler:(void (^)(UNNotificationPresentationOptions))completionHandler
{

}

-(void)userNotificationCenter:(UNUserNotificationCenter *)center didReceiveNotificationResponse:(UNNotificationResponse *)response withCompletionHandler:(void (^)(void))completionHandler
{

}

-(void)application:(UIApplication *)application didReceiveRemoteNotification:(NSDictionary *)userInfo fetchCompletionHandler:(void (^)(UIBackgroundFetchResult))completionHandler
{

}
```

Comment: Can you please give the relevant code for Objective - C.

Comment: I have added the code in AppDelegate, still no difference the screen goes black.

Comment: Yes, xcode warning still exisiting. The code which I have posted is my full code of AppDelegate.

Comment: Change application setting . goto Settings -> YourApplication -> Notifications -> Allow Notifications - SetON